# Wamp or other php server define overall global constants

Tags: php, constants, global

I was wondering if we should always define constants by each php client request. there is some fixed values for the same webpage that we never change example : max and min allowed age, height or weight; or other values that are more as configurations constants line when we use them as codes for different things, is there a way to define those **one time as the server is launched** and use them by each php script running?

I was thinking to use php.ini to store those values.. But I don't think it is a good idea to mix my codes with others ones. So I'm asking if there is a way to do that?

Yea and about not polluting the global namespace, we can easily use one array to store all of them.

**EDIT:** I save those constants in an .ini file.

**EDIT 2:** here is a sample of my constants ini file:

```
; **********************  Personal data  **********************
min_height = 100
max_height = 250
min_weight = 30
max_weight = 400

; **********************  Action Constants  **********************
act_create_account = 1
act_add_picture = 20
act_add_comment = 30

; friendship
act_add_friendship = 10
act_reject_friendship = 11
act_accept_friendship = 12
act_unfriend = 13

;blocking
act_block = 40
act_unblock = 41

; **********************  Messages Constants  **********************
max_message_query_number = 21

; **********************  messages chat flags  **********************
message_receiver_unseen = 2
message_sender_unseen = 1
```

Comment: Environment variables seem like a potentially good fit for this to me.

Comment: What about storing these values in a specific namespace or class?

Comment: @pnovotnak and PEMapModder, thank you for reply. well there is two points here. one (added in edit)  is that I use a file to store those values. and second which is the real purpose for my question is why should we load them by each script running it's about performance here. as far as they never change can't we load them once to memory and use them when ever needed?

Comment: @fekirimalek you can put all these data in a PHP file that declares these constants, or in a JSON file that you load and define values.

Comment: As a general practice, loading a PHP file that declares constants does negligible effect to the performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Environment Variables

https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Easy to use

Comment: thanks a lot, i learned something new here thought not for my exact question, but i will consider to use that. may be to replace **global "varname"** to access to global consants (declared as vars) inside functions

Answer (score 1):

I understand your point here but when dealing with scalability, distribution and/or migration, it should be more ideal to have these items pre-set by your application and that there is no manual interaction between the maintainer and the server in subject.

Best example is that you may not want to set max and min allowed age, height or weight everytime you deploy your application in a new environment or server.

In addition, configuration variables such as database connection details and settings like API keys and secrets are more reasonable to be manually configured per server as these are the kind of information you don't want to include in your repository since these are sensitive and must be private.

Comment: thank you for replying well, i agree with the first point, for the second I was more thinking about a file that contains all the constants and not to set them one by on. for the third point i  agree about the security concern though the constants i talk about here are common and not "classified". i wait a bit may be for other suggestions and i mark this as accepted.